# repeat text to speech at Onclicklistner android

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I want to develop app for kids that have two arrayList the second array contain four element and from this array one element will be select randomly and that element will be pass to TextToSpeech method to speech by smart phone first time it work fine but when again i call the same methods at onclicklistner for textView the TexttoSpeech class not working on second time below is my code can any one correct that ....... i am confuesed that where is the problem in my code ............

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

static ArrayList<Integer> LOneTEN_DigitsArr, LoneFOUR_DigitsArr;

static int i, LoneArr_SpVal, pick_speekDgt;
static TextView leftTop_text, rightTop_text, leftBottom_text,
        rightBottom_text;
public static Context baseContext;
static TextToSpeech tts;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     // set ids of four textviews 
    leftBottom_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bottomLeft_txtV);
    rightBottom_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bottomRight_txtV);
    leftTop_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.topLeft_txtV);
    rightTop_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.topRight_txtV);
    baseContext = getBaseContext();
      // below implementation at OnInitListener
    tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(),
            new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInit(int status) {
                    if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                        tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                        speakText(String.valueOf(pick_speekDgt));
                    }
                }
            });
     // initialize array list members 
    LOneTEN_DigitsArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    LoneFOUR_DigitsArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    leftBottom_text.setOnClickListener(this);
    rightBottom_text.setOnClickListener(this);
    leftTop_text.setOnClickListener(this);
    rightTop_text.setOnClickListener(this);
     // call below method to create 10 digits ArrayList and also call
     // rest of the methods inside tenValues_Lone()
    tenValues_Lone();

}

// inside onclick the method tenValues_Lone() and rest of methods will be call again and again      
//when user click on textview
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bottomLeft_txtV:

        tenValues_Lone();
        break;

    case R.id.bottomRight_txtV:

        tenValues_Lone();

        break;

    case R.id.topLeft_txtV:

        tenValues_Lone();

        break;

    case R.id.topRight_txtV:

        tenValues_Lone();

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

/**** create array of 10 digits for first level first it will be create ****/
public static int tenValues_Lone() {

    LOneTEN_DigitsArr.clear();
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
        LOneTEN_DigitsArr.add(i);
        System.out.print(String.valueOf(LOneTEN_DigitsArr));

    }
  // insinde tenValues_Lone() method i call below method
    fourValues_Lone();
    return i;
}

public static void fourValues_Lone() {

    LoneFOUR_DigitsArr.clear();
    for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
        Collections.shuffle(LOneTEN_DigitsArr);
        int pickValues = LOneTEN_DigitsArr.get(j);
        if (!LoneFOUR_DigitsArr.contains(pickValues)) {
            LoneFOUR_DigitsArr.add(pickValues);
        } else {
            j--;
        }
    }
       //insinde fourValues_Lone() method i call below method also 
    Lone_GetSet_Text();
}

/******************** get text from array and set to textView ********************/
public static void Lone_GetSet_Text() {
    pick_speekDgt = getRandom(LoneFOUR_DigitsArr);

    leftBottom_text.setText(String.valueOf(LoneFOUR_DigitsArr.get(0)));
    rightBottom_text.setText(String.valueOf(LoneFOUR_DigitsArr.get(1)));
    leftTop_text.setText(String.valueOf(LoneFOUR_DigitsArr.get(2)));
    rightTop_text.setText(String.valueOf(LoneFOUR_DigitsArr.get(3)));

    Toast.makeText(baseContext,
            "Speak" + "\b" + String.valueOf(pick_speekDgt), 300).show();

}

/**** get digits randomly from Array ****/

public static int getRandom(ArrayList<Integer> array) {
    int rnd = new Random().nextInt(4);
    int Val = array.get(rnd);
    return Val;
}

public static String speakText(String toSpeak) {
    toSpeak.toString();

    tts.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    return toSpeak;

}
```

}

below is my logcat but i dont think it show some error or exception

```
  09-10 15:35:13.809: D/STATUSBAR-NotificationService(2265): enqueueToast()
  09-10 15:35:13.834: I/SurfaceFlinger(1909): id=224(7) createSurf 0x40dc5214 (1x1),1 flag=0,    
  Uoast
  09-10 15:35:13.834: I/SurfaceFlinger(1909): SurfaceFlinger : eMagnificationFactorChanged.     
  magnificationFactor=1.0
  09-10 15:35:13.834: I/SurfaceFlinger(1909): SurfaceFlinger : eZoomPositionChanged.  zoomX=0.0    
  zoomY=0.0
  09-10 15:35:13.834: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2265): setHidden false
  09-10 15:35:13.849: D/PowerManagerService(2265): acquireWakeLock flags=0x2000000a    
  tag=KEEP_SCREEN_ON_FLAG uid=1000 pid=2265   myUID=1000 myPID=2265 myTID=291  1
  09-10 15:35:13.869: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2265): setHidden false
  09-10 15:35:14.399: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2265): setHidden false
  09-10 15:35:14.399: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2265): setHidden false
  09-10 15:35:14.879: W/PowerManagerService(2265): Timer 0x3->0x3|0x3
  09-10 15:35:15.824: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2265): setHidden false
  09-10 15:35:16.349: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2265): setHidden false
  09-10 15:35:16.349: I/SurfaceFlinger(1909): id=224 Removed Uoast idx=5 MapSz=3
  09-10 15:35:16.349: I/SurfaceFlinger(1909): id=224 Removed Uoast idx=-2 MapSz=3
  09-10 15:35:16.354: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2265): setHidden false
  09-10 15:35:16.354: D/PowerManagerService(2265): releaseWakeLockLocked flags=0x0    
  tag=KEEP_SCREEN_ON_FLAG myUID=1000 myPID=2265 myTID=2509
  09-10 15:35:16.359: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2265): setHidden false
  09-10 15:35:17.864: W/PowerManagerService(2265): Timer 0x3->0x3|0x0
  09-10 15:35:23.704: W/SignalStrength(2265): getGsmLevel=4
  09-10 15:35:23.704: W/SignalStrength(2265): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 18 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1    
   -1 -1      
  -1 -1 gsm|lte 4)
  09-10 15:35:23.704: W/SignalStrength(2602): getGsmLevel=4
   09-10 15:35:23.709: W/SignalStrength(2265): getGsmDbm=-77
  09-10 15:35:23.709: W/SignalStrength(2265): getDbm=-77
  09-10 15:35:23.709: W/SignalStrength(2265): getGsmAsuLevel=18
  09-10 15:35:23.709: W/SignalStrength(2265): getAsuLevel=18
  09-10 15:35:23.714: W/SignalStrength(2602): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 18 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1   
  -1 -1     
  -1 -1 gsm|lte 4)
   09-10 15:35:23.714: W/SignalStrength(2602): getGsmLevel=4
  09-10 15:35:23.714: W/SignalStrength(2602): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 18 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1   
  -1 -1      
 -1 -1 gsm|lte 4)
 09-10 15:35:23.714: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(2602): onSignalStrengthsChanged      
 signalStrength=SignalStrength: 18 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 gsm|lte 4 level=4
 09-10 15:35:23.719: W/AlarmManager(2265): FACTORY_ON= 0
 09-10 15:35:24.849: D/BatteryService(2265): update start
 09-10 15:35:24.854: D/BatteryService(2265): level:13 scale:100 status:2 health:2 present:true      
 voltage: 3728 temperature: 401 technology: Li-ion AC powered:false USB powered:true      
  icon:17303231      
  invalid charger:0
 09-10 15:35:24.859: D/BatteryService(2265): Dormant mode is always on
 09-10 15:35:24.859: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(2602): onReceive() - ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
 09-10 15:35:24.864: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(2602): onReceive() - level:13
 09-10 15:35:24.864: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(2602): onReceive() - plugged:2
 09-10 15:35:24.864: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(2602): onReceive() - BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
```

Comment: `not working on second time` then you should get some errors,post logcat.

Comment: @PiyushKukadiya check my edit quetion i added loggat

Comment: i dont think its show some error....

Comment: `speakText(String)` is only called once, when your TTS instance is initialized. It's not called from your `onClick(View)` callback.

Comment: thanks @AlexisPigeon i did .... like you said..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did just change the below code in onCreate...

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(),
        new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                    speakText(String.valueOf(pick_speekDgt));
                }
            }
        });
```

to

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
```

and implement oInitListner....  like below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnInitListener{}
```

and use onInit() as mentioned below

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
        speakText(String.valueOf(pick_speekDgt));

    }
   }
}
```